# how to dispaly the qtip for the particular textbox if validation fails

Tags: javascript, jquery, qtip, qtip2

I am trying to learn qtip jquery plugin.I want to display the qTip for fields which have fails validation.I have tried below code but it is not working.Please let me know am i doing correct or not.And suggest any plugins which makes validation easy in relates to qTip.

*HtML*

```
<input name="issueNumber" id="issueNumber" label="" 
 placeholder="Issue number" title="Please enter issue number"></input>
```

*JQuery*

```
//I used ternary operator
($('#'+namespaceInJs+'issueNumber').val()==null || 
 $('#'+namespaceInJs+'issueNumber').val()== '')
 ?displayQTip():
 alert("The value is"+$('#'+namespaceInJs+'issueNumber').val());
```

*JavaScript*

```
 //I have used this function in ternary operator.Calling if validation fails.
    function displayQTip(){
        alert("IN displayQTip ");
        $('#'+namespaceInJs+'issueNumber').qtip({
            overwrite: false,
            show: {
                event: false,
                ready: true
            },
            hide: false,
            style: 'cream',
            position: {
                my: 'left center',  // Tool tip arrow place
                at: 'right center', // Place of the tool tip to the text box or target item
                target: $('#'+namespaceInJs+'issueNumber'),
            }

        });
    }
```

Comment: By validation failing, you mean following condition is satisfying? ($('#'+namespaceInJs+'issueNumber').val()==null || 
 $('#'+namespaceInJs+'issueNumber').val()== '')

Comment: Yes,If it satisfies above condition it has to show qtip for that textbox.(That condition tells that if textbox empty show qtip)